# I want to connect two network to the Internet at the same time but use second one

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7

Ioperate a small LAN Gaming Center and I connected the computers in a Server/Client mode using ethernet with a switch.

Im accessing the internet through a modem connected to a server (logically). Everything works fine, but the ISP has a *really* bad connections sometimes. So bad, that completing any tasks with it is impossible. When that's the case, I disable my ethernet connection from "Change adapter Settings" in Windows and then connect through a WiFi hotspot.

Once I do that, the clients are no longer reachable. So I am trying to stay connected to my ethernet network *and* use the internet connection from WiFi.

Im using Windows 7, on both server and clients. Also I mm using Smartlaunch for client control.

For a better understanding of what im trying to achieve:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Yd-zfIOqVQ

Comment: I would suggest that you explain more Vetter your network setup and how you think to use 2 Gateways at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the network connection priority, could you try this:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-priority-order-network-adapters-windows-10

Regards,
Diego.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is mainly a routing problem. Just change the default gateway (or default route) to the IP that you would like to use as gateway.

The syntax for Windows 7 looks like this:

```
C:\> route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <IP-of-gateway) metric 30 if <Interface number>
```

With this command you can chose which gateway and/or which interface to use. If you already have a active default route, just delete it:

```
C:\> route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <IP-of-gateway>
```

You active configuration can be displayed with:

```
C:\>route print
===========================================================================
Schnittstellenliste
 11...00 50 56 99 29 73 ......Ethernet-Adapter für vmxnet3 <-- interface number
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.10.254    192.168.10.232    261 <-- default route
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
[...]
```